# gameObject turns into an Object when transferred to an Array

Tags: arrays, object, unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

I'm new to Unity.

I have an array of GameObjects which I declared using

`var shades:GameObject[];`

Now, I had to convert this to an Array using

`var allShades =new Array(shades);`

but it seems like the gameObjects have turned in Objects because I can no longer use, for example

`allShades[index].GetComponent(MyScript);`

It gives me this error: 'GetComponent' is not a member of 'Object'

I'm not even sure of all the things that I have done here, hehe!

I have been googling but I can't find the solution for this.

Any help Pls?? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use `.GetComponent` because `allShades` is an array (and an Array is an Object) and not a `GameObject`. You need first to access the `GameObject` inside it using `allShades[index]` and then you can use `.GetComponent`

See [Unity Reference about Arrays](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Array.html) too.

Comment: @ Marco Acierno - Hi! Thanks for your reply :) But I actually used an index. And still get the error. The example in my post (`allShades[index].GetComponent(MyScript);`) was incorrect. I just updated it :) I have fixed my problem by using an array of integers which represent the elements inside `shades` array. But I think that the solution is too dirty. I believe there is another way.

Comment: You want to use an Array of Array? Then it's allShades[index1][index2]. I don't noticed that shades was an array

Comment: No, I don't think I have to use an array of array (or a 2-dimentional array, I guess?). What I am trying to do is to randomly access the elements inside my array shades one by one and use each in a game challenge. I have to record which elements have been used so it won't be repeated in the next challenges. I made it that way so that I can save in the database which elements have been used when the player saves the game, and then retrieve them when the user resumes the game.

Comment: I thought about creating a copy of the array and sort it randomly but in that case, I will have to save the sorted array in the database, which I don't know how to do.